# Neo4j rake aborted! No such file or directory - wget http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-1.7-unix.tar.gz

Tags: rake, neo4j, wget, rake-task

Trying to install and run a simple Neo4j app from Max Demarzi's "d3_js_intro" app on GitHub. Issuing the command `rake neo4j:install`, I get the message shown below. Questions:

1. **Q**: What is the root cause of wget failing to get the file; a file that appears to exist in exactly the place expected? (Note: the URL following the error message "No such file or directory" is valid; that file exists there... so message is incorrect. Why?) **A**: the root cause was that wget is not installed on a Mac OSX machine. If you are running a Mac OSX machine, you too will need to install wget.

I've tried:

1. I've manually downloaded the file (http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-1.7-unix.tar.gz) that the wget was failing to get.
2. extracting the file to the app root directory.

Questions related to manually recovering from this problem:

1. **Q**: Does the manually-extracted directory need to be named anything special? (i.e.: "Neo4j", "neo4j", etc.). **A**: It would have to be called "neo4j", but the fix (below) eliminates the need to do this.
2. **Q**: What configuration files would I need to modify (and how) in order to get the app to see the neo4j server? **A**: the fix below eliminates the need to deal with this.

The gem files reads:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'neography'
gem 'haml'
gem 'json'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rack-test'
  gem 'net-http-spy' 
end
```

The Rakefile reads:

```
require 'neography/tasks'
require './d3.rb'

namespace :neo4j do
  task :create do
    create_graph
  end
end
```

Thanks for anything you can provide
- HisHighnessDog

```
rake neo4j:install --trace
** Invoke neo4j:install (first_time)
** Execute neo4j:install
Installing Neo4j-community-1.7
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - wget http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-1.7-unix.tar.gz
/Users/tomjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/neography-0.0.26/lib/neography/tasks.rb:44:in ``'
/Users/tomjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/neography-0.0.26/lib/neography/tasks.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
...
...
/Users/tomjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/tomjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tomjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/tomjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => neo4j:install
```

## Should I be concerned that the Rakefile does not contain a task entry for 'install', while the command I'm running is `rake neo4j:install`?

**Solution**: the root cause for the error message is that (OSX machine default): wget is not installed.

**Recovery**: Install and configure wget:

1. curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.14.tar.gz
2. tar -xzvf wget-1.13.tar.gz
3. cd wget-1.14
4. ./configure --with-ssl=openssl
5. make
6. sudo make install
7. which wget (to confirm wget is now installed)

Use the current wget download from gnu org's website.

Comment: ` No such file or directory - wget http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-1.7-unix.tar.gz` . do you need more explanation? try to download it first, and than specify the file. do not specify it with `wget`

Comment: @ulkas: I've updated the question to clarify what I'm looking for and what I've tried. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download, unzip and start a Neo4j server. The version is not relevant in this case. Go to http://neo4j.org/download for instruction and download links.